# Parse.com: Multiple scheduled jobs

Tags: parse-platform, task

In my app I want to have multiple background jobs. In the free plan I get one concurrent background job. If the jobs times collide what happens? Will the jobs be queued or dropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jobs are dropped. This Parse App was allowed 2 scheduled jobs, and this is what happened when four were scheduled to run in the same minute:

[image: Failing jobs "too many running"]

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Queue, here's a example:

Tasks is a object with functions that the queue is able to run.

You then create Jobs in you table with two attributes, method:String params:Object

e.g. method:'fetchVenue' :params: {'id':'1234'}

You then set parse to run the queue function every minute

```
tasks = {}
tasks.fetchVenue = function(params) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    //some async tasks
    promise.resolve("fetchVenue called with params:"+params);   
    return promise

}

tasks.fetchUser = function(params) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    //some async tasks  
    promise.resolve("fetchUser called with params:"+params);    
    return promise
}

Parse.Cloud.job("queue", function(request, status) {

    var jobCount = 0
    var query = new Parse.Query('Job');
    query.notEqualTo("complete", true);
    query.each(function(job) {  

        if (tasks.hasOwnProperty(job.get('method'))) {      

            tasks[job.get('method')]().then(function(completion){
                jobComplete(job)
                jobCount++ 
                status.message(completion);
            })  

        } else {
            status.message("job not found "+job.get('method'));
        }
    }).then(function(){
        status.success(jobCount+" jobs processed");
    }, function(error) {    
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
    })

});

var jobComplete = function(job){
    job.set('complete',true)
    job.save()
}
```